# windows phone 8.1 tracking location accurately and in both of the road's sides

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, gps, location, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to build a navigation app in which I have to track the location of a driver while driving. I want to get the house building number on his right and on his left in any moment(if exist).
I am currently using the Geolocator.

First I set for it those propeties:

```
        _geolocator.ReportInterval = 1000;
        _geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionAccuracy.High;
```

Than I update it when the position changed:

```
async private void OnPositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            pos = e.Position;
            getAdress(pos.Coordinate.Point);

        });

    }
```

Than I get the adress from there like that:

```
   private async Task getAdress(Geopoint point)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("trying get adress");
        MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(point);
        String location= result.Locations[0].Address.Town+" "+result.Locations[0].Address.Street+" "+result.Locations[0].Address.StreetNumber;
```

The first problem is that the adress I am getting includes usually onlt the town and sometimes the street, but not the number. Is there a way to make it more accurate?

The second question is, how can I get the adress in both sides of the road?

Comment: The accuracy of the location data (once you got an accurate GPS location) depends on the service you are using. What service does your MapLocationFinder utilize?

Comment: I am using: Windows.Devices.Geolocation,    

 creating:  Geolocator _geolocator = new Geolocator();

Comment: Ok, personal opinion: The default reverse-geocoding that comes with windows is pretty bad, especially outside US. If you need really detailed location data, I recommend using Here or Google location service.